# PHP: Loop through query to create a bullet list in table form

Tags: php

PHP 7.1.7

I'm really new to PHP and having troubling thinking through this or finding a good example.

For the code below, I'm simply making a table of query results.   What I need to do is loop through the query for each unique UID to create a bullet list in table form.  So, the table output is a UID in COLUMN 1 and then COLUMN 2 of the table contains a new row for each LOG_TEXT (and where the UID would only be echo'd on the first pass of the loop).

Example:

User24:     •Opened Door 1

•Opened Door 2

•Opened Door 5

•Opened Door 6

User33: •Opened Door 1

•Opened Door 2

•Opened Door 5

•Opened Door 6

```
<?php include 'db_connect.php'; ?>                  
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"
        SELECT uid, log_text 
        FROM logs l
        WHERE (l.log_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-31')
    ");     

    echo "<table class='table_standard_grey_with_border' >
    <tr>
    <th>UID</th>
    <th>LOG TEXT</th></tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['uid'] . "</td>";                
        echo "<td>" . $row['log_text'] . "</td>";                       
    }               
    echo "</tr></table>";           
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order your query-result by userId, so all actions by the same user are 'grouped' together.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"
    SELECT uid, log_text 
    FROM logs l
    WHERE (l.log_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-31')
    ORDER BY uid
");
```

And within your PHP, just keep track of the previously printed userId and print an empty cell if it is equal to the previous one:

```
$previousUid = null;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    if ($previousUid === $row['uid']) {
        echo "<td></td>"; // Empty cell
    } else {
        echo "<td>" . $row['uid'] . "</td>";                
        $previousUid = $row['uid'];
    }

    echo "<td>" . $row['log_text'] . "</td>";    
    echo "</tr>";                   
}
```

Comment: _"Just keep track of the previously printed userId:"_ ... __and__ don't forget to _sort_ your query results by uid, otherwise this will get rather "mixed" results.

Comment: Thank you very much.   Your code worked perfectly.  I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way to do this is to fetch the data from the query into a multidimensional array before displaying it.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"
    SELECT uid, log_text
    FROM logs l
    WHERE (l.log_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-31')
");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[$row['uid']][] = $row['log_text'];
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

This will give you an array of data that can be displayed in an HTML view more simply, so that your data access code can be separated from your presentation code. This grouping will work whether or not you include an `ORDER BY` clause in your query, but you probably should do so anyway to be sure the data displays in the order you expect it to. It looks like `ORDER BY uid, log_date` would make sense for this data.

```
<table class='table_standard_grey_with_border'>
    <tr>
        <th>UID</th>
        <th>LOG TEXT</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($data as $uid => $log_texts): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $uid ?></td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                <?php foreach ($log_texts as $log_text): ?>
                    <li><?= $log_text ?></li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

A disadvantage to this approach is that it will be a little slower than displaying each row as you fetch it, and will consume more memory.